# Scrollbar is always on bottom when loading a table in Tabulator

Tags: tabulator

Everytime I load a table, the scrollbar appears at the bottom of it.

Why is it happening? Is there a way I can set it to the top of my table?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I dont believe there is any (easy) control over the location of the scrollbar in HTML5. Bottom and Right is the standard UI location.

Comment: agreed, this is standard scroll bar behaviour in any browser